# Provide a unique list of customer id’s and account numbers which have ordered both products 711 and 712 after July 1, 2008

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

The question is from AdventureWorks2008R2

I tried this query, but I only want Customers who ordered both the products 711 and 712. For example, CustomerID 11441 has ordered productid 711 and 712, so only 11441 shall be displayed

```
Select DISTINCT(oh.CustomerID), oh.AccountNumber, CAST(oh.OrderDate as DATE) OrderDates, od.ProductID
From Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
Inner Join Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
WHERE od.ProductID BETWEEN 711 AND 712
AND CAST(oh.OrderDate as DATE) > '2008-07-01'
ORDER BY oh.CustomerID
```

#### Screenshot of my output

[image: Screenshot of my output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    oh.CustomerID, oh.AccountNumber,
    CAST(oh.OrderDate as DATE) OrderDates, /* doesn't really make sense as a plural */
    od.ProductID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
WHERE CAST(oh.OrderDate as DATE) > '2008-07-01'
AND (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID)
        FROM SalesOrderDetail od
        WHERE od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
            AND od.ProductID IN (711, 712)
    ) = 2
ORDER BY oh.CustomerID;
```

Here's one way using a correlated subquery. By the way, what you were trying to do with `DISTINCT` in your original query won't work.